# How can I show mathematically the time complexity of this function is O(N)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

```
int foo(N){
   if(N <= 1){
       return 0
   }else{
       return 1 + foo(N-1)
   }
}
```

I can tell that the time complexity of this program is O(N) but I am unsure on how to prove it mathematically? If I can get some hints I'd grealy appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you say you can tell when you literally can't tell? (Rhetorical.)

Comment: $f(n)=1+f(n-1)$ are you sure about $O(n)$?

Comment: (If something looks just *too* obvious, try *proof by contradiction* - wait, you may note the procedure looks something else that might work in a proof, too.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use induction on input.

For example, in your foo,
to show that foo(N) uses exactly N comparisons,

**Base case:** foo(1) uses 1 comparison

**Induction hypothesis:** foo(N) uses N comparisons

**Step case:** foo(N+1) does one comparison and then call foo(N), thus in total, does N+1 comparisons.

You can prove similar statement for addition or all operations, and then you can give a time complexity based on those number of operations.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by *show mathematically*. If you want to be very formal, you will need to explain several things:

- Model of computation.
- Syntax and semantics of your programming language, and an algorithm for converting it into "machine code".

We don't typically explain these things explicitly. When analyzing algorithms, we typically assume that RAM machine model, which isn't really one concrete model, but an "idea" of a model; the exact definition usually doesn't matter.

(As an aside, if we worked in the bit complexity model, the running time would increase to $\Theta(n\log n)$.)

Often converting code or pseudocode to RAM machine "machine code" is rather unambiguous, as is the case here (although we have to be careful that our RAM machine is expressive enough to support recursion!). We can set up a recurrence for the running time $T(n)$ of your procedure in terms of the input $n$. If $n \le 1$ then $T(n) = \Theta(1)$, and otherwise $T(n) = T(n-1) + \Theta(1)$. At this point, it is routine to reach the solution $T(n) = \Theta(n)$.

Proving the recurrence *mathematically* would involve converting your C code to RAM machine "machine code", which you are probably not willing to do. Therefore the argument above isn't a completely formal proof. However, in computer science we are content with proofs at this level of detail. Similarly, in mathematics we often imagine we operate in a formal system, but we never actually write out proofs in this formal system; we are content with a level of detail which is enough to convince us that the proof is valid, that is, can be converted to a completely formal proof.

The field of *program verification* is in a sense a formalization of these informal techniques. There are systems which can take your program, convert it into some sort of intermediate code, set up the recurrence relation, and determine the asymptotic running time, possibly outputting a completely formal proof in the end.